# In Kotlin Multiplatform can I have an 'expect' type that is a simple type on one platform and a parameterized type on another?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, type-alias

Conceptually I want to do this:

```
// Expect file (commonMain)
expect class PlatformDir
    
// Platform-specific implementation for JVM
actual typealias PlatformDir = File
    
// Platform-specific implementation for Linux/macOS
actual typealias PlatformDir = CPointer<DIR>
```

The simple JVM type is accepted but the parameterized type of Linux/macOS is not:

> Expected class 'PlatformDir' has no actual declaration in module
>  for Native The following declaration is
> incompatible because number of type parameters is different:
> public actual typealias PlatformDir = CPointer
>
> Type arguments in the right-hand side of actual type alias should be
> its type parameters in the same order, e.g. 'actual typealias Foo<A,
> B> = Bar<A, B>'
>
> Actual typealias 'PlatformDir' has no corresponding expected
> declaration The following declaration is incompatible because number
> of type parameters is different:
> public final expect class PlatformDir

Moving the parameterized type first into its own typealias also doesn't work:

```
private typealias CPointer_DIR = CPointer<DIR>
actual typealias PlatformDir = CPointer_DIR
```

It still complains about the wrong number of type parameters and has this additional error:

> Right-hand side of actual type alias should be a class, not another type alias

I'm very much a noob in Kotlin and JVM as well as Kotlin Multiplatform so I feel this must be possible without wrapping both in a class. Googling I can't find anybody discussing this and the AI chatbots seem to just clutch at straws that get more and complex and don't build either.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a simple type for JVM and a parameterized type for Native platforms, but unfortunately, Kotlin doesn't support having different numbers of type parameters in expect and actual declarations.

However, you can achieve your desired outcome with a slightly different approach using a generic class in your expect declaration and then providing the actual implementations. Here's an example:

```
// Expect file (commonMain)
expect class PlatformDir<T>

// Platform-specific implementation for JVM
actual typealias PlatformDir<T> = File

// Platform-specific implementation for Linux/macOS
actual typealias PlatformDir<T> = CPointer<DIR>
```

In this case, you're using a generic class in your expect declaration, and then for each platform, you provide the actual implementation. For JVM, the type parameter T is not actually used, while for Native platforms, it's used as expected.

Keep in mind that this approach can be somewhat confusing, as the type parameter T is not really necessary in the JVM implementation. It's more of a workaround to maintain compatibility between different platforms.

Comment: Ah the AI chatbots were suggesting something similar that I didn't quite grok and couldn't get to work. Your explanation is nice and clear. I thought there might be some way of telling it that we're not expecting a type param named DIR but creating the type by using DIR. I don't knew what terminology or if there's something like this in other languages so didn't try to explain it, and also thought there might be another way, which there is. Thanks!

Comment: Actually this gives me errors like this: `Expected class 'PlatformDir' has no actual declaration in module multiplatform-test.jvmMain for JVM The following declaration is incompatible because number of type parameters is different:
public actual typealias PlatformDir<T> = File defined in root package in file jvmMain.kt` and `Type arguments in the right-hand side of actual type alias should be its type parameters in the same order, e.g. 'actual typealias Foo<A, B> = Bar<A, B>'`